# Swift: Replace exact word in string

Tags: regex, string, replace, swift2

For the past two days I've been struggling to find out how to replace exact word in a string using either some of the string functions in XCode or by using Regular Expressions. Is this even possible to accomplish? By I mean by that is for example to create a word censoring filter which prohibits the use of the word 'H e l l', and replaces it with '****'. Unfortunately all the things I have tried, I have ended up replacing words that contains 'H e l l', like in 'Hello'.

Please keep in mind that I am fairly new to Xcode, as I started by journey last week.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/)

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.  Also check out word boundardies in regex - \b.

Comment: @dustmouse this is currently what I have so far: var str = "This is a replaced string" let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\b" + word[1] + "\\b", options: .CaseInsensitive) str = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(str, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<str.utf16.count), withTemplate: replace[1]) label.text = str Unfortunately, this only allows me to replace 1 word at once. I want to be able to replace multiple words from two arrays(string - words, and replace words) - and I have tried to use both || and && but this doesn't seem to work. I have also tried to search on google.